# How to use a function with dynamic value in an ExtJS template

Tags: javascript, web, extjs, frontend

I created a template in ExtJS. I can also call a function from there without any problems. I can call it with a hard value. This time I want to use a dynamic value like that:

```
'<tpl for="myArray">',
    '<div style="color: {[myfunction("#{Color}")]}; background-color:#{Color};">',
        '{myVal}',
    '</div>',
'</tpl>',
```

The compiler can interpret the background-color, but nut the color of my div element. I don't know I to pass the color value correct in my function call: {[myfunction("#{Color}")]}.

With a hard value it would work:

```
'<tpl for="myArray">',
       '<div style="color: {[myfunction("#000")]}; background-color:#{Color};">',
              '{myVal}',
       '</div>',
'</tpl>',
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I found out my solution:

```
'<tpl for="myArray">',
    '<div style="color: {[myfunction(values.Color)]}; background-color:#{Color};">',
        '{myVal}',
    '</div>',
'</tpl>',
```

The magic key word is **values** with the required property added. No quotes. No brackets.

Comment: where is this `myfunction` and exaclty what you doing with this `myfunction`?